# Word for pulling a punch in karate

Tags: words, sports

During karate training my (English) karate teacher uses a word that sounds like "son dame". He says that this describes the action of stopping your punch just before making contact with the opponent.

I cannot find this word or any variant spelling of it on any English language karate site. Nor can I find any Japanese equivalent on any Japanese site. I've tried　そんだめ, そんだめい, そんだめえ. I tried replacing そん with ぞん, すん, ずん etc.

I'm sure half of these English-Japanese karate words are made up. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Not the same word, but your sensei will also use the word "kime" (focus) for pulling punches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's 「[寸止]{すんど}め」 （＾＾）

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AF%B8%E6%AD%A2%E3%82%81

Answer (score 7):

It’s 寸止め (すんどめ), from 寸 (a very short distance) and 止める (to stop)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, Chocolate beat you by 20s, so no tick :-(

Comment: ^ いあ、回答は、私のほうが後でした。。。